# Multiplying hundreds of matrices using cuda

Tags: matrix, cuda, matrix-multiplication

I am writing a program which requires to multiply hundreds of matrices in parallel using CUDA. Can somebody explain how to perform this operation.

I have seen that Kepler architecture is capable of dynamic parallelism. Has somebody used this architecture and if yes, which Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: Are all the matrices the same size ?

Comment: What size are the matrices? Where does the dynamic parallelism come into play? Or is that a different question?

Comment: The latest CUBLAS libraries come with a batch mode for matrix multiplication which allows exactly this as long as the matrices are the same size - http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_3_6

Comment: [batchCUBLAS example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#batchcublas)  and [api reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_8_2).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get fast performing matrix multiply in parallel using CUDA is through the [ArrayFire](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire) CUDA library using the [GFOR loop](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/page_gfor.htm).  Here's some code that does what you want:

```
int n = 8, int m = 8;   // dimensions
int t = 10;             // number of different matricies
array A = randu(m,n,t); // many matricies
array B = randu(m,n);   // one matrix
array C = zeros(m,n,t); // destination

// multiply C=A*B for all A, at the same time
gfor (array i, A.dims(2)) {
    C(span,span,i) = matmul(A(span,span,i), B);
}

print( A );
print( B );
print( C );
```

ArrayFire automatically tiles out the computation efficiently for execution on the GPU.  All that is optimized behind the scenes for you.  I find it to be faster than trying to write it by hand myself.